# FileNotFoundException al querer ejecutar un reporte hecho con iReport

Tags: java, jsf

Al querer correr un reporte hecho con iReport (el primero que hago), me lanza el siguiente error FileNotFoundException.
Entiendo que no encuentra el camino al archivo, pero no me queda claro como
especificarla, intente de varias maneras, he aqui las ultimas,  para si alguno puede indicarme que estoy haciendo mal. 
Primer Intento:

```
        try {
        String compiledReport = "d:\\java\\movimientosporfecha.jasper";
        JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(compiledReport);

        Map parametros = new HashMap();

        parametros.put("pdefec", this.defec);
        parametros.put("phafec", this.hafec);

        JasperPrint j = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, connection);
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(j, false);
        jv.setTitle("Reporte de Movimientos por Fecha");
        jv.setVisible(true);
  } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);           
    }
```

Segundo Intento:

```
try {

        String compiledReport = "d:\\java\\movimientosporfecha.jasper";
        URL in = this.getClass().getResource(compiledReport); 
        JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(in);

        Map parametros = new HashMap();

        parametros.put("pdefec", this.defec);
        parametros.put("phafec", this.hafec);

        JasperPrint j = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, connection);
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(j, false);
        jv.setTitle("Reporte de Movimientos por Fecha");
        jv.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

En ambos casos me lanza el mismo error!

El reporte existe en la carpeta!

Y tambien probe distintas formas de especificar la ruta, por ejemplo:

String compiledReport = "d:\java\movimientosporfecha.jasper";

String compiledReport = "d://java//movimientosporfecha.jasper";

O bien especificando la ruta completa a la carpeta de los reportes en el proyecto:
"D://Java//GastosJSF2//src//main//java//reportes//movimientosporfecha.jasper"

Nunca Funciona!

Answer (score 1):

En Java hay manera de sacar el directorio en el cual estas trabajando lo cual es más facil a la hora de trabajar con fichero que esten dentro de las carpetas del proyecto, unas de las opciones son las siguientes:

> System.getProperty( "user.dir" );
> new File(".").getCanonicalPath();

por lo cual tu variable quedaria de la siguiente manera:

> String compiledReport = System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) + "\src\main\java\reportes\movimientosporfecha.jasper";
>
> String compiledReport = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\src\main\java\reportes\movimientosporfecha.jasper";

Otra recomendación seria que pusieras tu carpeta de reportes a raiz del proyecto a si te facilitas mas la obtencion de las ruta, quedando de la siguiente manera:

> "D://Java//GastosJSF2//reportes//movimientosporfecha.jasper"

de esta manera quedarian las siguientes variables:

> String compiledReport = System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) + "\reportes\movimientosporfecha.jasper";
> String compiledReport = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\reportes\movimientosporfecha.jasper";